# Show/hide div inside li on click?

Tags: angular

I have ngFor for `li` and on every `li` i have `click`. What i want is to show/hide `div` in `li` when user click on li. Any suggestion how can i do that? Every `li` have different `ptechnologyName`

```
<li *ngFor="let billingAccount of billingAccounts" [ngClass]="showRecipient == 'billingAccount?.ptechnologyName' ? 'activerec': 'notactive'" (click)="showRecipient = 'billingAccount?.ptechnologyName'" >
                                    <span ><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span>
                                    {{billingAccount?.ptechnologyName}}
                                    <div *ngIf="showRecipient == 'billingAccount?.ptechnologyName'">
                                        <table class="custom-table">
                                            <tr (click)="openBaCustomer(billingAccount)">
                                                <td>{{billingAccount?.id}}</td>
                                                <td>{{billingAccount?.customerName}}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
```

In my case open all li and all divs.. i want to open only which one is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an attribute showRecipient as a property of your BillingAccount class:

```
export class BillingAccount {
    id: number;
    ptechnologyName: string;
    customerName: string;
    showRecipient: boolean;
}
```

Example of billingAccounts array in your component:

```
billingAccounts: BillingAccount[] = [
     {"id": 1, "ptechnologyName": "ptech1", "customerName": "cust1", "showRecipient": false },
     {"id": 2, "ptechnologyName": "ptech2", "customerName": "cust2", "showRecipient": false },
     {"id": 3, "ptechnologyName": "ptech3", "customerName": "cust3", "showRecipient": false },
     {"id": 4, "ptechnologyName": "ptech4", "customerName": "cust4", "showRecipient": false }
];
```

You can then toogle this property to show/hide div on click:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let billingAccount of billingAccounts" [ngClass]="billingAccount.showRecipient == 'billingAccount?.ptechnologyName' ? 'activerec': 'notactive'"
        (click)="billingAccount.showRecipient = !billingAccount.showRecipient">
        <span><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span> {{billingAccount?.ptechnologyName}}
        <div *ngIf="billingAccount.showRecipient">
            <table class="custom-table">
                <tr (click)="openBaCustomer(billingAccount)">
                    <td>{{billingAccount?.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{billingAccount?.customerName}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Another solution:**

Add an array of boolean (showRecipient) as an attribute of your component's class:

```
billingAccounts: BillingAccount[];
showRecipient: boolean[];
```

After fetching data from your webservice, fill in the showRecipient array:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // Fetch from backend:
    this.billingAccounts = [
        {"id": 1, "ptechnologyName": "ptech1", "customerName": "cust1" },
        {"id": 2, "ptechnologyName": "ptech2", "customerName": "cust2" },
        {"id": 3, "ptechnologyName": "ptech3", "customerName": "cust3" },
        {"id": 4, "ptechnologyName": "ptech4", "customerName": "cust4" }
    ];    
    // Fill in the showRecipient array
    this.showRecipient  = this.billingAccounts.map(it => false);
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let billingAccount of billingAccounts;  let i = index" [ngClass]="billingAccount.showRecipient == 'billingAccount?.ptechnologyName' ? 'activerec': 'notactive'"
        (click)="showRecipient[i] = !showRecipient[i]">
        <span><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span> {{billingAccount?.ptechnologyName}}
        <div *ngIf="showRecipient[i]">
            <table class="custom-table">
                <tr (click)="openBaCustomer(billingAccount)">
                    <td>{{billingAccount?.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{billingAccount?.customerName}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I' m getting data from api, i cannot add showRecipient inside BillingAccount

Answer (score 0):

You have to take **extra div inside li** and apply class condition on that as below:

```
<div *ngFor="let billingAccount of billingAccounts"  (click)="showRecipient = 'billingAccount?.ptechnologyName'" >
                            <li [ngClass]="showRecipient == 'billingAccount?.ptechnologyName' ? 'activerec': 'notactive'">
                                <span ><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span>
                                {{billingAccount?.ptechnologyName}}
                                <div *ngIf="showRecipient == 'billingAccount?.ptechnologyName'">
                                    <table class="custom-table">
                                        <tr (click)="openBaCustomer(billingAccount)">
                                            <td>{{billingAccount?.id}}</td>
                                            <td>{{billingAccount?.customerName}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                             </li>
                            </div>
```

Comment: when i click on first li it open div inside that li but also inside other li open divs

Comment: i want to open only li that is clicked not all of them

Comment: then you have to apply For loop in outer div and then place class on li, let me update answer

Comment: if you add plunker, we can help you better

Comment: li only can be child of ul... i cannot add div arround li inside ul